# Redirect console output (not all data redirected C#)

Tags: c#, redirect, console

If use default redirect from console

```
proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();                    
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

proc.OutputDataReceived += proc_OutputDataReceived;
proc.Exited += proc_Exited;
proc.ErrorDataReceived += proc_ErrorDataReceived;
proc.Start();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

There are problems (tested on Windows Git bash msysgit)

1. In OutputDataReceived come not all data.
2. In OutputDataReceived not come data of text color.
3. In ErrorDataReceived come wrong data.

Screen shots:

git bash console

[git bash console](http://ase.com.ua/img2.jpg)

redirected data

[redirected data](http://ase.com.ua/img4.jpg)

The questions:

1. There are way get correct data by redirection?
2. There are another way to get correct data from console?

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about "Accept"

Comment: You are working with a Unix program.  That requires dealing with the quirks of Unix terminal I/O.  The rectangles are escape sequences that perform terminal functions.  The underlying Unix library has a very appropriate name, it is "curses".

Comment: It's sad, but there must be a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not found correct redirection console input and output.

My solution for task:

1. Run console application.

   ```
   Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
   proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
   proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
   proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "";
   proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
   proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

   proc.Start();

   int count = 0;
   //wait console
   while (proc.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
   {
       Thread.Sleep(50);
       count++;
       if (count == 50)
           return;
   }
   ```
2. Allow copy-paste from to console.

   ```
   //Attach to console
   DllImport.ConsoleFunctions.AttachConsole(proc.Id);
   //Get console output handle
   IntPtr cHandleO = DllImport.GetStdHandle(-11);
   //Set Quick edit Mode mode
   DllImport.SetConsoleMode(cHandleO, 0x0040);
   //Deattach from console
   DllImport.FreeConsole();
   ```
3. View console output on Form.

   ```
   //Set my Panle as console window parent 
   DllImport.SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, panelConsole.Handle);
   DllImport.SendMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, 0x0112, 0xF030, 0);
   //Resize
   DllImport.SetWindowPos(proc.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, panelConsole.Width,     
       panelConsole.Height, 0x0040);
   //Hide border and title
   DllImport.SetWindowLong(proc.MainWindowHandle, -16, 0x10000000 | 0x00200000);
   ```
4. Send command from TextBox to console.

   ```
   private DllImport.INPUT_RECORD[] PrepareData(string data)
   {
       DllImport.INPUT_RECORD[] rec = new DllImport.INPUT_RECORD[data.Length + 1];
       for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
       {
           rec[i].EventType = 0x0001;
           rec[i].KeyEvent = new DllImport.KEY_EVENT_RECORD();
           rec[i].KeyEvent.bKeyDown = true;
           rec[i].KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = 0;
           rec[i].KeyEvent.UnicodeChar = data[i];
           rec[i].KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = 1;
           rec[i].KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = data[i];
           rec[i].KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = (ushort) DllImport.MapVirtualKey(data[i], 0);
       }
       rec[data.Length].EventType = 0x0001;
       rec[data.Length].KeyEvent = new DllImport.KEY_EVENT_RECORD();
       rec[data.Length].KeyEvent.bKeyDown = true;
       rec[data.Length].KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState = 0;
       rec[data.Length].KeyEvent.UnicodeChar = '\n';
       rec[data.Length].KeyEvent.wRepeatCount = 1;
       rec[data.Length].KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = '\n';
       rec[data.Length].KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode = (ushort) DllImport.MapVirtualKey(0x0D, 0);

       return rec;
   }

   uint count = 0;
   //Fttach to console
   DllImport.AttachConsole(proc.Id);
   //Get input handle
   IntPtr cHandleI = DllImport.GetStdHandle(-10);
   //Prepare data
   DllImport.INPUT_RECORD[] data = PrepareData(tb.Text);
   //Write to console
   DllImport.WriteConsoleInput(cHandleI, data, data.Length, out count);
   //Deattach
   DllImport.FreeConsole();
   ```

[Use PInvoke.net for some functions](http://www.pinvoke.net)

[Sample project](https://github.com/AlexandrM/GitBashGUI)

Answer (score 0):

StreamWriter input;
        Process p = new Process();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["exe"];
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;//自定义shell
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;//避免显示原始窗口
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;//重定向标准输入（原来是CON）
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;//重定向标准输出
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;//重定向错误输出流
        p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(Process_OutputDataReceived);
        p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(Process_OutputDataReceived);

        try
        {
            p.Start();//GO
            input = p.StandardInput;//重定向输入
            p.BeginOutputReadLine();//开始监控输出（异步读取）
        }
        catch (Win32Exception ) {
            MessageBox.Show("指定的可执行文件无效");
            Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Comments are very *explanatory* :)